# Radio box, get the checked value [iCheck]

Tags: jquery, icheck

Basic radio box

```
<div class="adv_filter">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Text" value="0"> Text</li>
    </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Text" value="0"> Text</li>
    </li>
</div>
```

iCheck transformation

```
<!-- iCheck output format
<div class="adv_filter">
    <li>
        <div class="iradio_square-orange checked" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;"><input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Text" value="0" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins></div> Text</li>

        <li>
            <div class="iradio_square-orange" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;"><input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Text" value="0" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins></div> Text</li>

</div> -->
```

***As you see the checked is attached to the div..***

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-orange',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-orange',
            increaseArea: '20%' // optional
        });
        $("li").on("click", "input", function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            //updateDataGrid(val);
            alert(val);
        });

    });
```

**Question and description**

Provided javascript code worked properly before adding the icheck plugin, 
*I am wondering how to get the same result in the icheck plugin. Its simple, on radio click it stores the value in variable later its passed further to functions.*

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/9ypwjvt4/

iCheck : http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

Comment: use events from plugin api

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Attach a handler to `ifChanged` event:

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert($(this).val()); // alert value
});
```

There are [11 ways to listen for changes](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/#callbacks):

- `ifClicked` - user clicked on a customized input or an assigned label
- `ifChanged` - input's checked, disabled or indeterminate state is changed
- `ifChecked` - input's state is changed to checked
- `ifUnchecked` - checked state is removed
- `ifToggled` - input's checked state is changed
- `ifDisabled` -input's state is changed to disabled
- `ifEnabled` - disabled state is removed
- `ifIndeterminate` - input's state is changed to indeterminate
- `ifDeterminate` - indeterminate state is removed
- `ifCreatedinput` -  is just customized
- `ifDestroyed` - customization is just removed

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ypwjvt4/1/)

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, one more question. I used to had also $("input[data-custom='Text1']").attr( 'checked', true ); , A default auto checker how to add this? I can't do it manually cause my radio list is generated from php

Comment: @user3793639 Great, you're welcome! Ask a new question for that. I will look for it.

Comment: Fine. Sadly I can post once 90 min :3

Comment: @user3793639 Oh, I see. Use this call [`$('input:first').iCheck('check');`](http://jsfiddle.net/9ypwjvt4/3/).

Comment: Well, Its not that simple for me I need target not the first, but the input data-custom="Text1"

Comment: @user3793639 Just pass the correct jQuery selector and call the method. Great. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Avoid using jquery as much as you can.
You can also use code below;

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    alert(event.target.value); // alert value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
// Check #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "checked", true );
 
// Uncheck #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "checked", false );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').on('ifChecked','.icheck', function(){
//considering icheck is the class of your checkbox and it is getting generated dynamically
});
```